# Algorithm for computing the sum of symmetric sums (better than $\mathcal{O}(2^N)$ )

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, subset-sum

Let denote $\mathbf{x} = \{x_1,x_2,...,x_N  \}$ with $x_i \in \Bbb R$ for $i=1,...,N$ and $f(\mathbf{x},n)$ be the $n$-th symmetric sum of the set $\mathbf{x}$

$$
f(\mathbf{x},n) = \sum_{\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n} \left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma_i}\right)
$$
with $\sigma_1,...\sigma_n \in \{1,2,...,N \}$ and $\sigma_i \ne \sigma_j$ for $i\ne j$

(the definition of the $n$-th symmetric sum can also be found [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Elementary_symmetric_sum))

Let define $g(\mathbf{x},a)$  be the sum of symmetric sum
$$
g(\mathbf{x},a)= \sum_{n=0}^N a^{\mathbb{mod}(n,2)} f(\mathbf{x},n) 
$$
with $a \in \Bbb R$ and
$\mathbb{mod}(n,2) = \begin{cases} 
1 \quad \text{ if } n \text{ odd} \\  
0 \quad \text{ if } n \text{ even} 
\end{cases}$

*Example 1: N = 2*:
$$
g(\mathbf{x},a)= 1 - a(x_1 +x_2) + (x_1 x_2)
$$

*Example 2: N = 3*:
$$
g(\mathbf{x},a)= 1 - a(x_1 +x_2+x_3) + (x_1 x_2+x_2 x_3+x_3 x_1) - a x_1 x_2 x_3
$$

The complexity of $g(\mathbf{x},a)$ is $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$ with a naive algorithm. Indeed, the sum $g(\mathbf{x},a)$ has exactly $2^N$ terms and we sum up the terms sequentially

$$
g(\mathbf{x},a)= \sum_{n=1}^N\left( a^{\mathbb{mod}(N,2)} \sum_{\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n} \left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma_i}\right)\right)
$$

**My question**: does there exist a better algorithm for computing $g(\mathbf{x},a)$ which is less complex than $\mathcal{O}(2^N)$?

*My attempt*: There exists special cases where $a=\pm 1$ that can factorize the sum $g(\mathbf{x},a)$ as follows
$$
g(\mathbf{x},a)= \prod_{n=1}^N(x_i+a)
$$
and then the sum can be computed in $\mathcal{O}(N)$. I try to find a mathematical method like this for $a \ne \pm 1$ without success. In fact, all difficulties lie on the modulo function $\mathbb{mod}(n,2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But $g(x,a)$ is linear in $a$ so if you can compute it efficiently for two different values of $a$ then you can compute it efficiently for all $a$?

Comment: But $x_1,x_2,...x_n$ are also variables.

Comment: But as a function of $a$ it is linear for each $x$, so simply compute $g(x,-1)$ and $g(x,+1)$ and fit a line through these points to get $g(x,\cdot)$ for this particular $x$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem becomes simple from this angle. Thank you for your answer!